# In truffle test using js, how to set the parameters after the `contract `?

Tags: testing, ethereum, solidity, contract, truffle

Such as `WhitelistedCrowdsale.test.js` in `openzeppelin-solidity`:

`contract('WhitelistedCrowdsale', function ([_, wallet, authorized, unauthorized, anotherAuthorized]) { ... }` in line 12.

why the parametes of `function(...)` is `_, wallet, authorized, unauthorized, anotherAuthorized`? Can they be other things? why?

Thanks!

Comment: For those trying to help, I believe this is the file: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/crowdsale/WhitelistedCrowdsale.test.js.

Answer (score 1):

Truffle injects the list of accounts available from the node you’re connected to. From the [Truffle docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests#use-contract-instead-of-describe-):

> The contract() function provides a list of accounts made available by your Ethereum client which you can use to write tests.

To use these accounts, you write your test case like this:

```
contract(‘MyContract’, function(accounts) {
  it(‘test1’, function() {
    const account = accounts[0];
    // do something with account
  }
});
```

`accounts` is just an array. The code from OpenZeppelin you posted is expecting there to be at least 5 accounts available in the node (the same array of accounts are available via `web3.eth.getAccounts()`). They are just decomposing the array into specific variable names. `_` is `accounts[0]`, `wallet` is `accounts[1]`, etc. You can name them whatever you want.